# Pandas- sum-products of Dataframe with another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe with values measured at specific places (columns) at various times (index).  For example (if I set my time index to integers):

```
data = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

> data:
>    A  B  C
> 0  1  2  3
> 1  4  5  6
> 2  7  8  9
```

I also have multiple sets of weights I would like to apply to the data:

```
weights = pd.DataFrame(index=['I', 'II'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], data=[[0.5, 0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 0.0, 0.5]])

> weights:
>       A    B    C
> I   0.5  0.5  0.0
> II  0.5  0.0  0.5
```

What I am in need of calculating is a row-by-row sum-product of weights*data, for my two different sets of weights.  e.g.:

```
> result:
>      I    II
> 1  1.5   2.0
> 2  4.5   5.0
> 3  7.5   8.0
```

I know how to get an individual column calculated, for example:

```
result_I = data.mul(weights[:].ix['I'], axis=1).sum(axis=1)

result_I:
> 0    1.5
> 1    4.5
> 2    7.5
```

Is there a way to create the result Dataframe outlined above, short of iterating over all rows, and concatenating?  Or is iteration/concatenation that the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic matrix multiplication problem. You can use `np.dot`:

```
In [190]: result = pd.DataFrame(np.dot(data, weights.T), columns=weights.index); result
Out[190]: 
     I   II
0  1.5  2.0
1  4.5  5.0
2  7.5  8.0
```

---

A shorter version, as pointed out by John Gait, is `result = data.dot(weights.T)`.

Comment: It absolutely is.  I guess I couldn't see the forest for the trees! :)  Thanks

Comment: @MarkD Glad to help. :) I did not know pandas data frames had their own dot function, but I guess they do so you can use that itself (it's the same but more compact code).

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame` has a `.dot` method.

```
In [806]: data.dot(weights.T)
Out[806]:
     I   II
0  1.5  2.0
1  4.5  5.0
2  7.5  8.0
```